# Laravel Filament: Array to Table

Tags: laravel-filament

I'm still learning laravel filament and I have a column called "products" which is a json data type. I want to display the concatenated values to the table.

```
foreach ($get as $item) {
            $groupProducts = [];
            foreach ($item->products as $product) {
                $groupProducts[] = $product['product_id'];
            }
            $groupConcatenatedProducts = implode(', ', $groupProducts); 
            $allGroupsConcatenatedProducts[] = $groupConcatenatedProducts; 
        }
        
    
        return $table->columns([
                    
                    Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('product_id')
                    ->$allGroupsConcatenatedProducts,
                    Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('product_name')
                    ->searchable(),
```